# JavaScript: Why so much abstraction/interfacing in Addy's Observer Pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, observer-pattern, observers

I'm working through the design pattern example for the Observer Pattern in Addy Osmani's book, "JavaScript Design Patterns". My question is why is it important that there are so many levels of abstraction in his implementation of the pattern?

For instance, in his example, just to **add** an observer ('push' an observer to an array), this involves:

- using the native `push()` method.
- creating a `ObjectList.add()` method.
- inheriting/extending the `ObjectList` object with the `Subject` object.
- creating the `Subject.addObserver()` method which to be used as an interface, but which uses the `ObjectList.add` method under the hood.
- extending the `Subject.addObserver()` method for new objects.
- Implementing it by calling the `addObserver()` method on the newly extended object.

Here's the code example for the design pattern in its entirety:

```
function ObserverList(){
  this.observerList = [];
}

ObserverList.prototype.add = function( obj ){
  return this.observerList.push( obj );
};

ObserverList.prototype.count = function(){
  return this.observerList.length;
};

ObserverList.prototype.get = function( index ){
  if( index > -1 && index < this.observerList.length ){
    return this.observerList[ index ];
  }
};

ObserverList.prototype.indexOf = function( obj, startIndex ){
  var i = startIndex;

  while( i < this.observerList.length ){
    if( this.observerList[i] === obj ){
      return i;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return -1;
};

ObserverList.prototype.removeAt = function( index ){
  this.observerList.splice( index, 1 );
};

function Subject(){
  this.observers = new ObserverList();
}

Subject.prototype.addObserver = function( observer ){
  this.observers.add( observer );
};

Subject.prototype.removeObserver = function( observer ){
  this.observers.removeAt( this.observers.indexOf( observer, 0 ) );
};

Subject.prototype.notify = function( context ){
  var observerCount = this.observers.count();
  for(var i=0; i < observerCount; i++){
 this.observers.get(i).update( context );
  }
};

// The Observer
function Observer(){
  this.update = function(){
    // ...
  };
}
```

And here's the implementation/usage:

HTML

```
<button id="addNewObserver">Add New Observer checkbox</button>
<input id="mainCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
<div id="observersContainer"></div>
```

Script

```
// Extend an object with an extension
function extend( extension, obj ){
  for ( var key in extension ){
    obj[key] = extension[key];
  }
}

// References to our DOM elements

var controlCheckbox = document.getElementById( "mainCheckbox" ),
  addBtn = document.getElementById( "addNewObserver" ),
  container = document.getElementById( "observersContainer" );


// Concrete Subject

// Extend the controlling checkbox with the Subject class
extend( new Subject(), controlCheckbox );

// Clicking the checkbox will trigger notifications to its observers
controlCheckbox.onclick = function(){
  controlCheckbox.notify( controlCheckbox.checked );
};

addBtn.onclick = addNewObserver;

// Concrete Observer

function addNewObserver(){

  // Create a new checkbox to be added
  var check  = document.createElement( "input" );
  check.type = "checkbox";

  // Extend the checkbox with the Observer class
  extend( new Observer(), check );

  // Override with custom update behaviour
  check.update = function( value ){
    this.checked = value;
  };

  // Add the new observer to our list of observers
  // for our main subject
  controlCheckbox.addObserver( check );

  // Append the item to the container
  container.appendChild( check );
}
```

Now I compared his implementation with other implementations of the same pattern (books and blogs). And it seems that Addy adds a ton more abstraction than other implementors of the observer pattern. The question is, why? Couldn't this be implemented more simply by inheriting from the `ObserverList` object? Does this achieve a greater degree of decoupling doing it the way Addy does? If so, how exactly is that? Doesn't the design pattern itself create a decoupling? Seems like the `Subject` object brings a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: The `Subject` object here is way more code that required.  It seems to me that it could either inherit from an `ObserverList` or it could contain a publicly accessible `ObserverList` and then in those cases it would not have to define a whole new observer interface and reimplement a whole bunch of methods that already exist in the `ObserverList` object.

Comment: This question feels like a discussion question + Primarily opinion based question to me.

Comment: @jfriend00: I think this question best suits SO, as it pertains to understanding the essential 'theory' of how this design pattern is implemented in JS in what's considered a fundamental/authoritative book on the subject. This is not simply an arbitrary code block requiring optimization.

Comment: @shmuli We're not a place to ask what's authoritative. It depends on your needs.

Comment: @jfriend00: this post isn't acceptable for codereview.stackechange.com because the code example belongs to someone else.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I wasn't asking what's authoritative. Instead, my question is more along the lines of how much of this is required for the basic pattern, and what's extra? And if in this case, there is anything that can be considered 'extra' by some, what utility/benefit does it serve, and how does it serve that utility?

Comment: @shmuli - does my answer give you what you were asking for?  If not,what is it missing?

Comment: @jfriend00 Great answer! Just one thing...How are we actually decoupling the 2 interfaces when the `Subject` object still relies heavily on the `ObserverList` object? I still don't see what we've accomplished by this. Could you please elaborate more on the decoupling factor? I'd like to understand more about that.

Comment: @shmuli - the interface to the `Subject` object is decoupled from the interface to the `ObserverList` object.  The implementation of the `Subject` object is still highly dependent upon the `ObserverList`. The difference is that if the `ObserverList` interface changes, you do not have to change the `Subject` interface, but you do have to fix the `Subject` implementation to work with the changed `ObserverList`.  Decoupling it in this way puts the burden on you (the implementor of the `Subject` object) to stay current, but allows you to never change the `Subject` interface. That's the decoupling.

Comment: @shmuli - this interface decoupling comes at the price of reimplementing an otherwise good interface, redocumenting an otherwise already documented interface and retesting a newly implemented interface.  So decoupling two interfaces is not always the best choice.  And, it should go without saying that anytime you use another object you have an implementation dependency on the interface of that object.  So all use of other code comes with that sort of dependency.  The question is whether your interface is coupled or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Couldn't this be implemented more simply by inheriting from the
>   ObserverList object?

Yes.  By inheriting, there would be no reimplementing of all the `ObserverList` methods.  Signficantly less code, less testing and less documentation.

> Does this achieve a greater degree of decoupling doing it the way Addy
>   does?

Yes, it does because the interface to the `Subject` object is not dependent at all on the `ObserverList` interface (because `Subject` has re-implemented its own interface to those methods so its interface is decoupled from the `ObserverList` interface.  This has its pros and its cons.  Reimplementing an interface should only be done with good reason because its mostly just a bunch of extra code that adds no actual useful functionality.

> If so, how exactly is that?

Hiding the actual interface to the `ObserverList` by reimplementing your own version decouples the two interfaces.  A change to the underlying `ObserverList` interface can be hidden by the `Subject` interface.  While the `Subject` implementation is still dependent and coupled to the `ObserverList` interface, the `Subject` interface itself is independent from the `ObserverList` interface.  But, there are plenty of reasons to not do this too so don't go thinking that every interface should be decoupled from every other interface.  That would be a disaster to follow that everywhere.

> Seems like the Subject object brings a lot of unnecessary code.

Yes, it does.

---

When you want to use functionality from another object and you want to expose some or all of that functionality to the customers of your own object, you have a number of design choices.

1. Your object can inherit from that other object, thus exposing its entire interface automatically (and allowing you to override some methods if desired).
2. Your object can contain an instance of that other object and expose that object publicly so that users of your object can get direct access to the other object without you reimplementing anything.  This would probably be my choice in this particular case so code using the publicly available observer within a `Subject` object would look like this:

   `var s = new Subject();
   s.observer.add(function() {
       // this gets called when subject is changed
   });`
3. Your object can contain a private instance of that other object and you manually create your own interface on top of that private instance.  This is what the code in your book is doing.

In OO-speak, these three choices are sometimes referred to as isA, hasA and hidesA.  In the first case your object "is a" `ObserverList` object.  In the second case, your object "has a" `ObserverList` object.  In the third case, your object "hides a" `ObserverList` object inside its implementation.

---

There are pros and cons to each design choice.  None of the choices is always the right or wrong way to do things as each has different pros/cons and which is the optimal choice depends upon the situation.

The case for option 1) inheriting is generally when your object is an extenstion of the base object and architecturally speaking it is thought of as just a more powerful version of the base object and/or it may override methods on the base object.  That isn't really the case here.  A `Subject()` object isn't a more powerful `ObserverList` object.  It's a different type of object that happens to use an `ObserverList`.

The case for option 2) of containing a public instance of an ObserverList and letting users of your object use that public instance is when your object is really a different kind of object, but it wants to use and expose to its users the functionality of another type of object.  That seems to me mostly what is happening here.

The case for option 3) is when you do not want any interface dependency between the interface to your object and any other interfaces.  In that case, you can't expose some other object's interface to let users of your object use those.  Instead, you have to cover any other interfaces with your own.  This means more code, more testing, more documentation and more maintenance.  But, a change in the underlying interface you are using does not necessarily cause a change to your own interface.  You have the option of hiding any underlying changes in interface (at the cost of a lot more work).  But, while gaining control, you also have more work.  If the `ObserverList` object adds three new methods, in the other two options those methods are immediately available to your users without you having to do any new work, but in option 3), you have to create new cover methods for them and test and document those before they can be available to your clients.